# Splitting an array at a given time

Tags: php, symfony

I'm still working on an intranet for students. So far, I've managed to do about 95% of what I expected, but I'm stuck.

My students can register to a project. Every project got a deadline, after this date, you cannot register anymore.

So, let's say I got 900 students, and 600 of them register to an activity. I created the "activity" entity, with the "registered" attribute, stocking all of the registered students.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Futur\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
public $inscrits;
```

So far, this works perfectly: my student apply to the activity, he is registered, but that's where the tricky part comes in: for every project, a student has to be corrected by 4 random registered students. I know how to create a random group within an array, I just have no clue on how to do it at a specific time. Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Describe *specific time*.

Comment: When the deadline comes. At this moment, registrations are closed, and the random groups are created.

Comment: Where do you wish to *split* the array? In your controller? What should happen then? Where and how do you define the 'closing' of a registration?

Comment: For the "closing part", I made it quite simple : once the deadline is passed, the "register" button does not appear anymore. I think this should be done in the controller. I used split, but I'm not sure it is the mot appropriate word, all I need to do is pick students from the "registered students" array to create random groups.

Comment: I don't understand your workflow at all. Maybe all you are looking for is a mysql query with the `RAND()` function? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: the workflow would look like this :
1) I create an activity, and set the deadline
2) My students register to this activity.
3) Deadline: they cannot register anymore. All of the registered students are stocked into an array (activity.registered)
4) Random groups are created within activity.registered

Comment: I guess you've never heard of cron? Just create a Symfony2 command that checks if any groups have to be created. Then run this command periodically using cron http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron